# AngularJS: Reading JSON in controller

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am having some problems exposing a field on my AngularJS controller. I have a webservice returning a JSON 'owner' object, with a field called 'Cave'. If this field has a null (or empty/whitespace) value, I want to hide an element in my view using ng-hide. To achieve this, I hope to expose the field 'hideCave' from the controller, shown in its entirety below:

```
function OwnerController($scope, OwnerFactory, $routeParams) {
    if ($scope.owner == null) {
        $scope.owner = OwnerFactory.getOwner($routeParams.id);
        //$scope.hideCaveat = $scope.owner.Cave == undefined;

        //Outputs 'Hide: {}?undefined'
        alert('Hide: ' + JSON.stringify($scope.owner) + '?' + $scope.hideCaveat); 
    }

    $scope.someButton = function () {
        //Outputs full JSON string when clicked
        alert('Hide: ' + JSON.stringify($scope.owner) + '?' + $scope.hideCaveat); 
    }
}

myApp.factory('OwnerFactory', function ($http) {
    return {
        getOwner: function (id) {
            var url = 'api/Owner/' + id;
            return $http.get(url)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

My data loads fine, but I can't get a value out of $scope.owner.Cave until I add a ng-click event any trigger it.

Example JSON return from web service:

```
{"FirstName":"David","LastName":"Lynch","Street":"Oak Dr. 7","ZipCode":"90210","Town":"Beverly Hills","Email":"","Cave":"Do not sell this man any more drugs"}
```

What am I doing wrong since I don't get the value?

Is my issue related to the fact I'm creating a global function for my controller? Should I use myApp.controller instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just access it as you would any other object

```
<div class="alert" ng-show="owner.Cave">{{owner.Cave}}</div>
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8YnC1tX88KdMbhoP2RDy?p=preview)**
In the plunker I just hardcoded the data.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Many good answers, but this one offers the simplest solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using ng-show="owner.Cave" in your template? It should work fine.

The reason why you get an empty object alerted is that the $http.get is not a synchronous function. It returns a promise - so by the time you reach alert you still only have the promise. Only once it has been resolved - such as before you click the button, do you see the actual data.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this. Enigma beat you to it, but the explanation about the promise was what I was missing. I'll keep that in mind in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @TroelsLarsen, you can still upvote other answers. It's true that you can only select on answer as the one that solved your problem. But you can upvote any that you found to be helpful.

Comment: @EnigmaRM: Not until I get 15 reputation, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

```
myApp.factory('OwnerFactory', function ($http) {
    return {
        getOwner: function (id) {
            var url = 'api/Owner/' + id;
            return $http.get(url);
        }
    }
});
```

and

```
$scope.owner = OwnerFactory.getOwner($routeParams.id).then(function(data){
     $scope.hideCaveat = data.owner.Cave == undefined;
});
```

since getOwner returns a promise.

edit

better use ng-hide or ng-show on the data you want to show or hide

```
<div ng-show="owner.Cave">cave infos</div>
```

Comment: As the other answers, you nailed my problem. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

add a watch at beginning of your controller, so "hideCaveat" is always there.

```
function OwnerController($scope, OwnerFactory, $routeParams) {
  $scope.$watch( 'owner.Cave', function(cave) {
    if (cave && cave.length > 0) {
      $scope.hideCaveat = false;
    } else {
      $scope.hideCaveat = true;
    }
  });
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But since I can just bind directly (no idea why I didn't try that first), I prefer that solution.